# Google Datalab read from cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

i know this question has been asked many times but all answers do not fit my request.
I would like to retrieve a csv file that is stored into cloud storage from datalab.
In order to re-use the code in a normal application i DO NOT want to use the datalab.storage library but the official cloud storage and without any magic.

Is it possible?
Up to now I did:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
blob = storage.Blob(gs_path, bucket)
# here I should put something equivalent to 
# data = data_obj.read_stream() if using datalab.storage
# %gcs read --object $uri --variable data if using magic
```

How to do using clean storage library?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Assuming you want it saved to a file, you can use blob.download_to_filename()

```
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name,
        destination_file_name))
```

Other options like download_as_string() and download_to_file() are [available as well](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/storage/google/cloud/storage/blob.py).

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/snippets.py
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/storage/google/cloud/storage/blob.py